# How to add a tabbar inside a card?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I was trying to implement the ui/ux for an app. I was trying to make a tabbar inside of the body in a card that have a summary like below.

[image]

I was trying to make the three tabbar as above. Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: This will help you to style the tab https://mightytechno.com/style-tabs-in-flutter-app/ @AimanIrfan02

Answer (score 1):

```
DefaultTabController(
  length: 3,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      elevation: 0,
      bottom: TabBar(
          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.redAccent,
          indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
          indicator: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
              color: Colors.redAccent),
          tabs: [
            Tab(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.redAccent, width: 1)),
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text("Flow \nReport"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Tab(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.redAccent, width: 1)),
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text("Consumption \n Report"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Tab(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.redAccent, width: 1)),
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text("Automated \n Alert"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]),
    ),
    body: TabBarView(children: [
      Icon(Icons.apps),
      Icon(Icons.movie),
      Icon(Icons.games),
    ]),
  )),
```

Hopefully this helps,
You can add a Flexible, if you want to have much bigger tab text. Icons can removed if needed.

Comment: Hi @Darsh Shah. I have tried your code and i always got an error that say:

RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.


Any Idea how i can remove this error?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with DefaultTabController, and use the tabbar wherever you want, like this:

```
  TabController _tabController;

  var tabIndex = 0;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      initialIndex: tabIndex,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
               
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: dimensions.defaultPadding),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue)
                    ),
                    child: TabBar(
                      controller: _tabController,
                        unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
                        indicator: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue)
                        ),
                        onTap: (index) {
                          setState(() {
                            tabIndex = index;
                          });
                        },
                        labelColor: Colors.blue,
                        tabs: <Widget>[
                          Tab(text: 'Flow Report'),
                          Tab(text: 'Comsuption Report'),
                          Tab(text: 'Automated Alert'),
                        ]
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
               
                Container(
                  
                    child: TabBarView(
                      controller: _tabController,
                      children: [
                        Content1(),
                        Content2(),
                        Content3(),
                      ],
                    ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I hope I've helped

Comment: Hi @Victwise. I have tried your code and i always got an error that say:

RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.


Any Idea how i can remove this error?

Comment: Wrap your widget under `Flexible`, This will make your Widget to take the size.